# C# Random number code check

Tags: c#, random

The below code is copied from a paper, undergrad work was linked to from a wikipedia page.   I believe I've spotted some flaws in the paper and some in the code but as I have no C# experience I just want to double check.

My understanding is that this code was meant to create a large psuedo totally random number but instead I believe it creates a large number which is a reoccuring smaller random number.
ie. 123123123 instead of 123784675. Can someone please confirm what the code does.

What I read here http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx and on Stackoverflow in various posts makes me believe that it's using the same seed and hence getting the same number each iteration and just appending that same number over and over.

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
counter = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
{
    StringBuilder largeRandomNumber = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
    { 
        int value = randomNumber.Next(11111, 99999);
        largeRandomNumber.Append(value); 
    }
}
```

Comment: In just a few seconds, I _ran_ your code and saw that wasn't the case... so -1 for not trying.

Comment: Looks completely fine to me... Take a look at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php

Comment: @Austin Salonen. I should have said I can't try I don't have a C# compiler assumed that it wasn't available free being from MS and all.

Comment: The command line compiler is included in the framework.  VS Express is free; Mono is free; there's likely a plug-in for Eclipse -- the options exist.

Comment: @Nikita Silvertruk. Thanks I'll be able check rest of bits I wasn't sure of.

Comment: the only drawback of that code is, that it will have a "smaller" amount of zeros, than a regular random number would have. Randoming between "0 and 9" would contain more zeros than the example, because the combination "00000" is NOT possible, while "11111", "22222" and so on are. Tiny Difference, but i would never bet on "0", when gambling :)

Comment: The sentence that caused me concern when I looked it up was "If you start off an instance of Random with the same initial state (which can be provided via a seed) and make the same sequence of method calls on it, you'll get the same results." Also saw similar language on here.

Comment: @RhuaidhriTynan That means the following: `Random r = new Random(1); r.next(0,10) // will return "2"` This will ALWAYS return 2 (even in 50 years!), cause thats, what "seed 1" will return! Use "no seed", then C# will take the "micro-time" which will Never ever be the Same number, unless you manage to generate the next number within the same micro second than the previous.

Comment: @dognose the micro time was the concern specifically in this case the random number is used for testing an algorithm the works better if there is any repeating of a sequence in the large number so was concerned this wasn't testing it properly.

Comment: Well, it "IS" still a Pseudo-random-number. If you want - for scientific testig purpose "better" random numbers, have a look at random.org

Answer (score 1):

Creates instance of random and loops through creating the next random number using random.Next(int min, int max) and appends this on the end of a string.  Essentially, it just creates one huge number for something.  Outer loop is garbage, not needed at all.  Random doesn't need to be seeded again after creation...keeps same seed and progresses correctly using the Next method.  Everything about this code "works" but seems pointless in any application besides learning about the random class.

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine.

Try it here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Random randomNumber = new Random();

       for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
       {
           StringBuilder largeRandomNumber = new StringBuilder();    

           for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
           { 
               int value = randomNumber.Next(11111, 99999);
               Console.WriteLine(value); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Yes, Seed is same but this line will make sure that you get different number on different run :

```
int value = randomNumber.Next(11111, 99999);
```

and since you are appending this number to a string to create large random number, this does what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is most likely that it will generate the same number if called quickly in succession, since Random is seeded with the current time. Unless they instantiated the `randomNumber` instance inside the loop however, for purposes of an example it works fine.

For example, if the code is plugged into a function like this

```
    public string GetLargeRandomNumber()
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        StringBuilder largeRandomNumber = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
            {
                int value = randomNumber.Next(11111, 99999);
                largeRandomNumber.Append(value);
            }
        }
        return largeRandomNumber.ToString();
    }
```

And called from a main function in quick succession it will return the same random number.

Comment: If you run the code in a function it will instantiate `randomNumber` with the same seed, thus returning the same number. Therefore, context is important.

Comment: Granted deleting comment and upvoting (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

`randomNumber` is seeded on [construction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx). `randomNumber.Next` is returning the next random integer between the two given integers based on the initial seed, and is not reseeded, thus giving 40000 new random numbers and appending them.

Not sure what the outer loop is for, it only runs once anyway